# Recompile TeeChart 2015.16 with Delphi 10.1 Berlin under Win 11

Tags: teechart, delphi-10.1-berlin

I could not Recompile even my RAD Studio Berlin 10.1 is installed properly in WIN 11.
I do get this error. What to do?
[image: RecompileIssue]